# In python, how to writing to cosmosdb from azure serverless function using info in function.json?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an azure function that is fed by httprequest and should store the given input into a cosmos collection, using CoreSQL.  The code is getting the data from the request in, but the data is never written to the db.

From my reading, I know a connection outward from a function needs to be defined in the function.json file.  My question do I need to use the values from the function.json to make my db connection?

If I do, do I get them from the azure.functions.Out object?  If so, how do I connect to the db given the function.json's "connection" string, which appears to be the db's 'PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING'.  Should I just split the connection string to get my url and key?

Alternatively, could I use the function's 'Application settings' to pass the values in, and if so, are they in my function's environment (os.getenv('xyz'))?

Thanks for any guidance, especially if it is in Python.

Answer (score 1):

[Consider the Following example](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v2functions/cosmos-trigger-cosmodb-output-binding):  **Function gets document data from Azure Cosmos DB Trigger,  and store data into Azure Cosmos DB by using Cosmos DB output binding**

**functions.json**

```html
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "docs",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "MyCosmosDBConnectionString",
      "databaseName": "testdb",
      "collectionName": "testcol01",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
    },
    {
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "outdoc",
      "databaseName": "testdb",
      "collectionName": "testcol02",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true,
      "connectionStringSetting": "MyCosmosDBConnectionString",
      "createIfNotExists": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**Create Cosmos DB Account and DB & Collection for testing**

Create a Cosmos DB Account

```html
COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT_NAME="azfuncv2db"
RESOURCE_GROUP="RG-azfuncv2"
az cosmosdb create \
    --name $COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT_NAME \
    --kind GlobalDocumentDB \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP
```

Create Database and Collection in the Cosmos DB that you've created

```html
# Get Key
COSMOSDB_KEY=$(az cosmosdb list-keys --name $COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --output tsv |awk '{print $1}')

# Create Database
az cosmosdb database create \
    --name $COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT_NAME \
    --db-name $DATABASE_NAME \
    --key $COSMOSDB_KEY \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP

# Create a container with a partition key and provision 400 RU/s throughput.
COLLECTION_NAME="testcol01"
az cosmosdb collection create \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --collection-name $COLLECTION_NAME \
    --name $COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT_NAME \
    --db-name $DATABASE_NAME \
    --partition-key-path /name \
    --throughput 400

COLLECTION_NAME="testcol02"
az cosmosdb collection create \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --collection-name $COLLECTION_NAME \
    --name $COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT_NAME \
    --db-name $DATABASE_NAME \
    --partition-key-path /name \
    --throughput 400

# Create a container for leaves
# 'leaves' need to be a single collection partition
# Please see also: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/930
LEASES_COLLECTION_NAME="leases"
az cosmosdb collection create \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --collection-name $LEASES_COLLECTION_NAME \
    --name $COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT_NAME \
    --db-name $DATABASE_NAME \
    --throughput 400
```

**Publish the function to the cloud**

```html
FUNCTION_APP_NAME="MyFunctionApp"
func azure functionapp publish $FUNCTION_APP_NAME --build-native-deps --no-bundler
```

**Add Functions App Settings**

```html
COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION="***************"
az webapp config appsettings set \
  -n $FUNCTION_APP_NAME \
  -g $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --settings \
    MyCosmosDBConnectionString=$COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  In my azure function's definition, this is my function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "cosmos",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "out",
      "ConnectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnection",
      "databaseName": "messages",
      "collectionName": "messages_1",
      "createIfNotExists": true
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return",
      "dataType": "string" 
    }
  ]
}
```

It describes three bindings,

1. The first is the input http trigger
2. My connection to the cosmos db, where

   - `cosmos` is the name.
   - the direction is `out`
   - the `ConnectionStringSettings` points to the CosmosDBConnection, which is defined as a function's Connection->Application settings.  The Application setting contains the CosmosDB Primary Connection String `AccountEndpoint=https://....`
   - `database` is the database it will write into
   - `collectionName` is the name of the collection, in the database
3. An http output connector used to return http responses.

In my python code, I use the `out` as a parameter passed in and write to it.

```
import azure.functions as func
from  azure.cosmos import cosmos_client


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, cosmos: func.Out[func.Document]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # your magic

    # create a dictionary, foo_bar in this case
    # On the parameter passed in, named cosmos, use the set() operator
    # in insert a Document, built from the dictionary

    cosmos.set(func.Document.from_dict(foo_bar))
```

No other setup of the database is needed.  It is handled by azure, processing the function.json file.  Just make sure your function.json's ConnectionStringSetting points to an attribute holding your connection string.

A few more tidbits

- watch your virtual network settings, so function and create the db.
- use the Microsoft 'func' package for local testing.
- Postman is a great tool for local testing.